# Trouble Connecting to Virtual Machine after IP address Change

Tags: networking, vmware

I have a VMware image running a copy of Fedora 11 which is hosted on a remote server. The remote server recently had its IP address change. I'm now unable to connect to my virtual machine. The server admin assures me that my virtual machine is running and assigned the new IP address. I have checked the firewalls and had the remote admin restart the VM instance. Neither of these fixed the problem.

How do I troubleshoot a remote server which I am unable to SSH to? I'm actually even unable to ping the remote IP (connection timed out).

Comment: What version of vmware is the host running? Is this vmware server, workstation, esx, esxi etc? Never mind, I see that this is a pretty old question that just got resurrected.

Answer (score 1):

First, have someone with console access verify the subnet mask and default gateway are correct.  Second, clear ARP.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest seeing if you can have the remote server restarted, and then your VM restarted again as well.

If the VM instance was not actually power cycled, it may have been only suspended.

So I guess I change my answer. Verify that the VM was truly restarted, Fedora loaded successfully, and then see if they will restart the remote server.

Can the owner of the remote server verify the IP and verify the VM has been restarted and loaded without errors?

Comment: Is there any way that the admin can directly connect to my virtual machine from the server console? If so, how? The admin does not really know much about vmware and is expecting me to send him a script to run.

Comment: I'm not sure. If he had local access, or desktop access, he should be able to pull it up locally. It all depends on how the VM is instanced. Hopefully someone with more experience in this sort of thing will come along and reply.

Comment: He does have local access, but the local machine only has a command line terminal (no GUI) and I haven't found much documentation from vmware about how to connect to a local vm from the command line. He did use the command line vm command to restart the vm instance.

Comment: He could try to telnet to the VM using the local machine, see if it is recognized on the IP. I don't know enough about VMWare command line to tell you more.

Comment: What would it mean if telnet fails? I don't think that ping can even reach the virtual machine (even though vmWare indicates that the vm is running at the IP address - I assume that VmWare is using some sort of administrative port to reach the vm image).